# Sandboxing DQL queries in Doctrine2

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

Is there a simple way to somehow filter DQL statements to be able to use DQL conditions in url query parameter for instance in a REST API? Like users/?q="firstName='John' AND contacts IS EMPTY".

Something like sandboxing mode in twig. Maybe a custom query walker could be used but probably someone has solved it already?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i created a custom AST Walker. Looks like it works. But it's not fully tested yet.

https://gist.github.com/maryo/6762610

Answer (score 0):

This is what custom Repository classes are for.  In your custom Repository class, you can create oneor more methods that accept parameters and use the querybuilder to build up your query depending on the url parameters passed.  See the documentation for the [QueryBuilder](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/query-builder.html) class for many examples.

Comment: I am not a beginner with Doctrine. I just want to use DSL in my REST API because i think it would be powerful, quite easy and user friendly. Just want to know if somebody has experience with it. Something like for example JIRA has https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Advanced+Searching